# Does the textmate vertical selection feature exist in Flex Builder or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder, textmate

In textmate on OS X there is a handy feature when you select text.

If you hold the option key down the cursor turns into cross-hairs and you can select a vertical column of text and paste it back as a vertical column with the lines rows preserved.

Does Flex Builder or Eclipse have the same feature? Not sure what to call it.

If so, what is the key combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse it is called Block Selection Mode and available in the newest version 3.5 (Galileo). The key combination to toggle it is Alt-Shift-A.

In Emacs this is called a rectangle and the commands working on these are called *-rectangle, e.g. kill-rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Just same Alt-Left MB and drag a selection box

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible from version 3.5 and above using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. See [here](http://www.vasanth.in/2009/03/31/eclipse-tip-block-selection-mode/).